# Why not disable the Ktlint role from the standard role set?

Tags: kotlin, ktlint

Why not disable the `filename` Ktlint role from the standard role set?

`build.gradle.kts`

```kotlin
plugins {
    id("org.jmailen.kotlinter") version "3.14.0"
}
```

`.editorconfig`

```
[*]
indent_size = 4
indent_style = space
trim_trailing_whitespace = false
insert_final_newline = true
max_line_length = 180

[*.{kt,kts}]
ktlint_standard = enabled
ktlint_experimental = enabled
ktlint_standard_filename = disabled
```

And `filename` role will be run and I get: `Lint error > [filename] File name mapping.kt' should conform PascalCase`.

I tried to configurate from https://pinterest.github.io/ktlint/rules/configuration-ktlint/#disabled-rules